# What is the replacement for Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()?

Tags: java, guava

I am upgrading from Google Collections 0.9 to 1.0. It seems `Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()` is no longer available. I was using it in the following construct:

```java
public static <K, V> Multimap<K, V> newConcurrentMultimap()
{
    return Multimaps.newMultimap( new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Collection<V>>(), new Supplier<Collection<V>>()
    {
        @Override
        public Collection<V> get()
        {
             return Sets.<V>newConcurrentHashSet();
         }
    } );
}
```

What would be the best replacement for Sets.newConcurrentHashSet() ?

Edit:
The reason for this construct is to have a multimap that is safe to read and write from multiple threads. It is used in a mostly-read scenario (and will be read a lot).

Comment: As you noted yourself in a comment below, this doesn't do what you want it to do anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Sets.newConcurrentHashSet` was withdrawn in 1.0rc1 ([commit log](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/detail?spec=svn80&r=80)).  I don't know the reason for the withdrawal, but you could use [the implementation](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/diff?spec=svn80&r=80&format=side&path=/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java&old_path=/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java&old=78) yourself:

```
Sets.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<V, Boolean>());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done for now. I am just wondering if it will do what I hope since the javadoc states that:
"The multimap is not threadsafe when any concurrent operations update the multimap, even if map and the instances generated by
factory are." I do not like to use the synchronized wrapper, since that no longer makes it concurrent but synchronized.

Comment: You're wondering whether it works because the javadoc tells you specifically that it doesn't work? :-)

Comment: It was withdrawn in a "one step back, two steps forward" manner; since we have plans to support concurrent Sets with a decent fraction of the options you get for maps with `MapMaker`, we didn't want to also be stuck with that `newConcurrentHashSet` method for all eternity. Sorry that said functionality hasn't appeared yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `MapMaker` and then use `newSetFromMap()`

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
```