# Thread-safe HashSet with Guava Collections

Tags: java, collections, hashset, guava

Like the title says, i would like to get a thread-safe HashSet using Guava Collections.
Are any available?

Comment: There would be no sense in making in threadsafe when it is already immutable, isn't it?

Comment: You're righy Willi. It will not be immutable. Several threads will mutate it concurrently.

Comment: By the way, don't prefer collections from Guava over JDK ones just because they're from Guava. Use each when they make the most sense for what you're doing.

Comment: @Colin: Totally agree, and in fact, my answer doesn't use any Guava classes at all, just what comes with the Java Concurrency Framework. :-P

Comment: @CollinD: Yeah, that's absolutely true. But i know well the java.util and java.concurrent collections. I've a hard program running and was trying to test the Guava Collections.

Comment: @santiago: If you really want to watch Guava shine, try the `Multimap` and `Multiset`, and the soft/weak keys/values with `MapMaker`. :-) (There are of course many other features, too many for me to cover.)

Comment: I've used this soft referenced map in a cache system and works real well new MapMaker().softKeys().makeMap()

Comment: @whiskeysierra: Never assume a "de facto" immutable class to be thread-safe. Such a class is not protected against memory visibility and code reordering issues and therefore it is NOT thread-safe.

Comment: @30thh What's the point in having and using an immutable class if I can't rely on it?

Comment: @whiskeysierra immutability has in general nothing to do with tread-safety. Only simple immutable objects with all the fields declared as final are guaranteed thread-safe. Please google for "JMM Safe Initialization".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be the right answer, Using the Sets class from Guava. Anyway the answer from @crhis was good intended.

```
Sets.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<V, Boolean>());
```

Comment: Actually, this is now deprecated, currently `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<V, Boolean>());` should be used.

Answer (score 28):

```
Set<K> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Boolean>());
```

Comment: Btw, all your points belong to me as i answered this question on the guava mailing list, 8 minutes before it was posted here ;)

Comment: @Willi: If I could assign them to you, I would, because I've already hit my rep cap for the day, so I'm getting absolutely no rep for this answer. :-P

Comment: You'd think there'd be a little bit more straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: @Colin: Welcome to Java! If you want straightforward, code in Ruby or Scheme. :-P

Comment: @Colin: it may seem like a monster code. But once you get in the API and familiarize with it, you get amazed how simple it get. It happened to me with the Streams Framework.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with most core Java APIs, this trick just strikes me as particularly unintuitive as the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

Java 8 introduces new way to create concurrent hash set - [ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet--)

```
Set<K> set = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
```

It's shorter than wrapping in `Collections.newSetFromMap`

Answer (score 4):

Google Collections ***had*** a factory method named [Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java?r=78#224) for a while.

Its implementation was similar to Chris's suggestion:

```
public static <E> Set<E> newConcurrentHashSet() {
  return newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>());
}
```

They had a *newSetFromMap()* method inside the *com.google.common.collect.Sets* class (written by Doug Lea with assistance from members of JCP JSR-166). That method was added to *java.util.Collections* in java 1.6.

It was withdrawn in Google Collections 1.0rc1, since there are plans to better support concurrent sets in Guava (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055700/what-is-the-replacement-for-sets-newconcurrenthashset)).

[This post](http://dhruba.name/2009/08/05/concurrent-set-implementations-in-java-6/) expands on the use of the "newSetFromMap" method to construct concurrent sets.

Comment: Google guava still has newConcurrentHashSet() method BTW. https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newConcurrentHashSet--