# Why does it.next() throw java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap, concurrentmodification

```
final Multimap<Term, BooleanClause> terms = getTerms(bq);
        for (Term t : terms.keySet()) {
            Collection<BooleanClause> C = new HashSet(terms.get(t));
            if (!C.isEmpty()) {
                for (Iterator<BooleanClause> it = C.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    BooleanClause c = it.next();
                    if(c.isSomething()) C.remove(c);
                }
            }
        }
```

Not a SSCCE, but can you pick up the smell?

Comment: Sounds like you already know what's wrong.

Comment: Okay may be a dumb question - what's SSCE or SSCCE? None of [these](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SSCE) seems relevant.

Comment: @CoolBeans: please check out [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - no wonder why you are a doc by day and a coder by night :)

Comment: If you are going to accept any answer Swagatika is more technically correct

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `Iterator` for the `HashSet` class is a fail-fast iterator. From the documentation of the [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator
>   throws a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of
>   concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly,
>   rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an
>   undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Note the last sentence - the fact that you are catching a `ConcurrentModificationException` implies that another thread is modifying the collection. The same Javadoc API page also states:

> If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one
>   of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally.
>   This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that
>   naturally encapsulates the set. If no such object exists, the set
>   should be "wrapped" using the [Collections.synchronizedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29) method. This
>   is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized
>   access to the set:
>
> ```
> Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet(...));
> ```

I believe the references to the Javadoc are self explanatory in what ought to be done next.

Additionally, in your case, I do not see why you are not using the [`ImmutableSet`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html), instead of creating a HashSet on the `terms` object (which could possibly be modified in the interim; I cannot see the implementation of the `getTerms` method, but I have a hunch that the underlying keyset is being modified). Creating a immutable set will allow the current thread to have it's own defensive copy of the original key-set.

Note, that although a `ConcurrentModificationException` can be prevented by using a synchronized Set (as noted in the Java API documentation), it is a prerequisite that all threads access the synchronized collection and not the backing collection directly (which might be untrue in your case as the `HashSet` is probably created in one thread, while the underlying collection for the `MultiMap` is modified by other threads). The synchronized collection classes actually maintain an internal mutex for threads to acquire access to; since you cannot access the mutex directly from other threads (and it would be quite ridiculous to do so here), you ought to look at using a defensive copy of either the keyset or of the MultiMap itself [using the `unmodifiableMultimap` method of the `MultiMaps` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#unmodifiableMultimap%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap%29) (you'll need to return an unmodifiable MultiMap from the getTerms method). You could also investigate the necessity of returning a [synchronized MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedMultimap%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap%29), but then again, you'll need to ensure that the mutex must be acquired by any thread to protect the underlying collection from concurrent modifications.

Note, I have deliberately omitted mentioning the use of a [thread-safe `HashSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629359/thread-safe-hashset-with-guava-collections/3629416#3629416) for the sole reason that I'm unsure of whether concurrent access to the actual collection will be ensured; it most likely will not be the case.

---

**Edit: `ConcurrentModificationException`s thrown on `Iterator.next` in a single-threaded scenario**

This is with respect to the statement: `if(c.isSomething()) C.remove(c);` that was introduced in the edited question.

Invoking `Collection.remove` changes the nature of the question, for it now becomes possible to have `ConcurrentModificationException`s thrown even in a single-threaded scenario.

The possibility arises out of the use of the method itself, in conjunction with the use of the `Collection`'s iterator, in this case the variable `it` that was initialized using the statement : `Iterator<BooleanClause> it = C.iterator();`.

The `Iterator` `it` that iterates over `Collection` `C` stores state pertinent to the current state of the `Collection`. In this particular case (assuming a Sun/Oracle JRE), a `KeyIterator` (an internal inner class of the `HashMap` class that is used by the `HashSet`) is used to iterate through the `Collection`. A particular characteristic of this `Iterator` is that it tracks the number of structural modifications performed on the `Collection` (the `HashMap` in this case) via it's `Iterator.remove` method.

When you invoke `remove` on the `Collection` directly, and then follow it up with an invocation of `Iterator.next`, the iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`, as `Iterator.next` verifies whether any structural modifications of the `Collection` have occurred that the `Iterator` is unaware of. In this case, `Collection.remove` causes a structural modification, that is tracked by the `Collection`, but not by the `Iterator`.

To overcome this part of the problem, you must invoke `Iterator.remove` and not `Collection.remove`, for this ensures that the `Iterator` is now aware of the modification to the `Collection`. The `Iterator` in this case, will track the structural modification occurring through the `remove` method. Your code should therefore look like the following:

```
final Multimap<Term, BooleanClause> terms = getTerms(bq);
        for (Term t : terms.keySet()) {
            Collection<BooleanClause> C = new HashSet(terms.get(t));
            if (!C.isEmpty()) {
                for (Iterator<BooleanClause> it = C.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    BooleanClause c = it.next();
                    if(c.isSomething()) it.remove(); // <-- invoke remove on the Iterator. Removes the element returned by it.next.
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Hover, heh thanks. I've had my fair share of battles before I made that statement.

Comment: the reference to synchronizedSet is misleading -- it does not give enough synchronization to prevent ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ, yes I would agree that in this particular case, the `Collections.synchronizedSet` invocation is useless.

Comment: the code is in a static method called from a @Test method and I don't see any concurrency. Is there how I could verify that the issue is indeed concurrency? If I use Collections.UnmodifiableSet it works till the remove statement (added).

Comment: @simpatico, I don't think you can invoke `remove` on an **unmodifiable** set; that would not make sense, for the set is meant to be unmodifiable, and typically it would result in an `UnsupportedOperationException` thrown.

Comment: @Vineet - I felt I shouldn't have written that. I understand why remove should not work, I just tried to motivate why I don't use the unmodifiable set. My quest this time was for evidence that the issue is indeed an issue of threads.

Comment: @simpatico, Also, I suspect that the original `ConcurrentModificationException` has got a lot to do with the `Collection.remove` call [which invalidates the iterator](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/02/02/java-concurrency-bugs-concurrentmodificationexception/). You should invoke the `remove` method on the Collection's iterator instead. Edit: I noticed your previous comment, and if your code is indeed invoking `Collection.remove`, then the cause of the CME exception is understood even in a single-threaded scenario.

Comment: It needs to be stated that most of this isn't technically correct.  Concurrent, in this context, only means within the same time frame.  You are not only iterating over a collection by trying to modify (concurrently modifying while iterating).  Though it can happen under a multithreaded environment, it is, in my experiences, far more likely through user error in a single threaded interaction.   All you have to do is look at the OPs example and that indicates user error.

Comment: Though I will say the ImmutableSet suggestion could help, the CopyOnWriteArrayList/CopyOnWriteArraySet gives you this support as well.

Comment: @John, if you noticed the question's history, the `Collection.remove` invocation was introduced in the last edit. Without that invocation, a CME would typically be thrown only if the underlying collection were to be modified by another thread. My comments above reflect that I'm well aware of iterator being invalidated on the `Collection.remove` call and the actual fix.

Comment: @Vineet The reason why I commented is because your answer is still technically incorrect, though your comments my validate most of what you're saying I wonder how many people will see you have 6 upvotes read your answer and continue on.  No where in the actual answer does it make any mention to the Iterator itself which is as we know the driving force behind the actual exception and not multiple threads.  I think your answer is confusing to people who are new to the topic.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that you are trying to modify the collection outside iterator.

How it works :

When you create an iterator the collection maintains a modificationNum-variable for both the collection and the iterator independently.
1. The variable for collection is being incremented for each change made to the **collection and and iterator.** 
2. The variable for iterator is being incremented for each change made to the **iterator.**

So when you call `it.remove()` through iterator that increases the value of both the modification-number-variable by 1.

But again when you call `collection.remove()` on collection directly, that increments  only the value of the modification-numbervariable for the collection, but not the variable for the iterator.

**And rule is : whenever the modification-number value for the iterator does not match with the original collection modification-number value, it gives ConcurrentModificationException.**

Comment: your rule makes sense (as it didn't smell of threads). Would you rewrite the code so that it works?

Comment: Its not my rule, thats how collection works internally with iterator. You can use it.remove() rather than removing directly from Collection.

Answer (score 3):

Vineet Reynolds has explained in great details the reasons why collections throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` (thread-safety, concurrency). Swagatika has explained in great details the implementation details of this mechanism (how collection and iterator keep count of the number of modifications).

Their answers were interesting, and I upvoted them. But, in your case, the problem does not come from concurrency (you have only one thread), and implementation details, while interesting, should not be considered here.

You should only consider this part of the `HashSet` javadoc:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator
>   throws a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of
>   concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly,
>   rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an
>   undetermined time in the future.

In your code, you iterate over your HashSet using its iterator, but you use the HashSet's own remove method to remove elements ( `C.remove(c)` ), which causes the `ConcurrentModificationException`. Instead, as explained in the javadoc, you should use the `Iterator`'s own `remove()` method, which removes the element being currently iterated from the underlying collection.

Replace

```
                if(c.isSomething()) C.remove(c);
```

with

```
                if(c.isSomething()) it.remove();
```

If you want to use a more functional approach, you could create a [Predicate](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and use Guava's [Iterables.removeIf()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#removeIf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method on the `HashSet`:

```
Predicate<BooleanClause> ignoredBooleanClausePredicate = ...;
Multimap<Term, BooleanClause> terms = getTerms(bq);
for (Term term : terms.keySet()) {
    Collection<BooleanClause> booleanClauses = Sets.newHashSet(terms.get(term));
    Iterables.removeIf(booleanClauses, ignoredBooleanClausePredicate);
}
```

PS: note that in both cases, this will only remove elements from the temporary `HashSet`. The `Multimap` won't be modified.