# How to fix java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error when trying traverse in ArrayList

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to add new object to my ArrayList if it satisfy the condition.
But it got me this ConcurrentModificationExeption when I tried to run it. Hope you could help me:

```
public void addTaskCollection(Task t){ 
    ListIterator<Task> iterator = this.taskCollection.listIterator();
    if(this.taskCollection.isEmpty())
        this.taskCollection.add(t);
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        if(t.isOverlapped(iterator.next()))
            this.taskCollection.add(t);
    }    
}
```

And here is the exeption error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
at Diary.addTaskCollection(Diary.java:36)
at Test.main(Test.java:50)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715322/i-keep-getting-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-how-to-fix-this

Comment: Collections.copy(destiny, source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with:

```
ListIterator<Task> iterator = this.taskCollection.listIterator();
boolean marker = false;

if(taskCollection.isEmpty())
    this.taskCollection.add(t);
else {
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      if(iterator.next().isOverlapped(t) == false)
         marker = true;
   }
}

if (marker == true)
    taskCollection.add(t);
```

to avoid ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Are you still getting ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to change your code a bit to get it compiled but the output is incorrect.

Comment: I finally got it right but don't have enough permission to answer my question. If possible, pls help me change update your code to mine as following:  </br>    `ListIterator<Task> iterator = this.taskCollection.listIterator();
        boolean marker = false;
        if(taskCollection.isEmpty())
            this.taskCollection.add(t);        
        
        else{
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            if(iterator.next().isOverlapped(t) == false)
                marker = true;               
        }
        if (marker == true)
        taskCollection.add(t);
        }`

Comment: Because your answer is quite close with my question so I will mark you as correct answer.

Comment: Weird because if you note my code is not modifying the collection that ie being iterated. Most likely while changing you somehow got your original code back. I suggest you to post your latest code in your question again and then I can help you better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11143/discussion-between-truong-thanh-dung-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

copy the array and change the original.

Comment: Try to copy using Collections.copy(destiny, source).

Comment: I tried to code `List<Task> tempCollection = this.taskCollection;
        ListIterator<Task> iterator = tempCollection.listIterator();
        if(tempCollection.isEmpty())
            taskCollection.add(t);
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            if(t.isOverlapped(iterator.next()))
                taskCollection.add(t);
        }` but it doesn't work

Comment: May be you can try this:                                             boolean modificationReqd = false;
for(Task task : this.taskCollection) {
 if() {//check the condition here 
  modificationReqd = true;
  break;
 }
}
if(modificationReqd) {
 this.taskCollection.add(t);
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you encounter a race condition. Multiple threads are accessing / modifying the same collection. Use a thread-safe List implementation.

Also, you must not modifying the collection (adding / removing) while iterating on it with an Iterator.

**EDIT**

*ConcurrentModificationExeption* sounds like taskCollection is accessed and modified by multiple threads at the same time (we can not say regarding the piece of code you provide if your program is single or multi threaded). If you share taskCollection between several threads, use a thread-safe list implementation.

But, the error here is actually clearly due to the fact that you add an element to the collection between  the moment you get an iterator on it and the moment you use this iterator. To fix that copy the new elements in temporary list and add them all in once at the end of the iteration.

Comment: So how could I modify the arraylist above, care to enlighten me?

Comment: The problem is just that you cannot modify a list whilst iterating over it with an Iterator... that's why you must copy it and modify the copy.

Comment: First, you have not enough input to say that the program is single-threaded. Anyway, we all agree that the error is due to the iteration/modification thing, and you're right to point my post was not clear. So I have just edited it. Second, here is the javadoc for ConcurrentModificationException : "... it is not generally permssible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances... "

Comment: You don't know that it is multithreaded. It could very well be single threaded

Comment: You don't know it is single-threaded either, that's all I said. I apologized for the fact that I may have wanted to imply that the problem was not due to the iter./modif. thing. This was confusing. But it still true that even it this error is fixed, ConcurrentModificationException may still occur, depending on how taskCollection is accessed. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html, the first reason given for such an exception is a race condition, and the iteration/modification in single-threaded environment come in second position only.

Answer (score 0):

Re-formatted Truong's answer from comments:

```
ListIterator<Task> iterator = this.taskCollection.listIterator();
boolean marker = false;

if(taskCollection.isEmpty())
  this.taskCollection.add(t);
else {
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if(iterator.next().isOverlapped(t) == false)
      marker = true;
  }
  if (marker == true)
    taskCollection.add(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two iterators.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Example_v3 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

          // Insert some sample values.
          list.add("Value1");
          list.add("Value2");
          list.add("Value3");

          // Get two iterators.
          Iterator<String> ite = list.iterator();
          Iterator<String> ite2 = list.iterator();

          // Point to the first object of the list and then, remove it.
          ite.next();
          ite.remove();

          /* The second iterator tries to remove the first object as well. The object does
           * not exist and thus, a ConcurrentModificationException is thrown. */
          ite2.next();
          ite2.remove();
     }
}
```