# Java iterator hasNext() method allways false

Tags: java, iterator, set

We have a HashSet of objects:

`private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<Client>();`

And iterator for it:

`private Iterator<Client> iterator = clients.iterator();`

Lets add object to that set and print out iterators `hasNext` method output:

`Client client = new Client(name);`

`clients.add(client);`

`System.out.println(iterator.hasNext());`

The output is: "`false`". Why?

Comment: Iterators don't work so well when you modify what they refer to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#iterator%28%29) for the [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class is a fail-fast iterator. From the documentation of the HashSet class:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator
>   throws a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of
>   concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly,
>   rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an
>   undetermined time in the future.

Here is a nice detailed explanation of the [Iterator internal implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237886/why-does-it-next-throw-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception).

Answer (score 3):

The iterator never changes once created--it only works on the elements that were in the set *when you got it*. It doesn't recognize that *after* you've created it, you added an element. Just re-get the iterator after all elements have been added.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Iterators break if you modify the collection externally after getting the iterator